# How to call a function using class instead of an object

Tags: php, class-structure

In my project, I want call a function xieTest() in Datasource class.

The content of Datasource class is :

```
namespace common;

class Datasource 
{

    public function __construct() 
    {

    }

    public static function xieTest()
    {
        $str = "xietest";
        return $str;
    }
}
```

And my html test.php code is :

```
<body style="height:100%" >
<?php 

$redis_obj = o1ws1v/class/common/Datasource::xieTest();

echo $redis_obj;

?>

</body>
```

My directory structure is：

```
/yjdata/www/www/test.php
/yjdata/www/www/o1ws1v/class/common/Datasource
```

It works fail, It seems nothing wrong.

Who can help me?

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file say?

Comment: The bit before a class name is for the namespace, not a directory name.  So either learn about autoloaders or include the file with the class in and reference it as `common\Datasource`

Comment: try thid **common/Datasource::xieTest();**

Comment: @Davit, I use $redis_obj = common\Datasource::xieTest(); But it works fail

Comment: @Davit That's basically what NigelRen suggested, only wrong. It's \, not /.

Comment: @stack Did you "autoload" or "include" your Datasource file?

Comment: @kerbholz, I use \ instead of /, But it also wrong. Both $redis_obj = common\Datasource::xieTest();  and $redis_obj = o1ws1v\class\common\Datasource::xieTest();  are wrong

Comment: @stack Not quite. `$redis_obj = common\Datasource::xieTest();` is the correct way to go *IF* you included your Datasource file beforehand

Comment: @kerbholz, yes, I added " include "o1ws1v/class/common/Datasource.php"; before  $redis_obj = common\Datasource::xieTest(); it works Ok